# PHP/DB pattern question

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, architecture

I have an app that works with an idea of "redemption codes" (schema: `ID, NAME, USES, CODE`). And example would be `"32, Stack Overflow, 75, 75%67-15hyh"`

So this code is given to the SO community, let's say, and it has 75 redemptions. You redeem it by entering some shipping info and the code. When entered, this check is preformed:

```
if (code exists){
    if (count_entries_where_code=$code < $uses_set_at_creation){
        //enter information into DB for processing
    {
    //echo "sorry, not a real code"
}
```

So the number of total uses is hardcoded, but the current # of redemptions is generated with a SQL query (`count_results from entry_data WHERE code=$code`). This part works fine, but here is the question:

At the <strike>view</strike> page where I manage the codes, I have the basic setup (in pseudo PHP, *with the real code separated into an MVC setup*):

```
$results = "SELECT * FROM codes";
foreach ($result as $code){
    echo $code->code;
    echo $code->name;
    //etc. It's actually all in a nice HTML table.
}
```

So I want to have a column listing "# of uses remaining on code". Should something like this be stored in the DB, and drawn out that way? It would be easier to generate with the `foreach` loop, but I don't usually prefer to store "generated" statistics like that. Is there a clever way to get those results onto the correct rows of the table created with the foreach loop?

(I'm fine with code so I don't need a working/great syntax example, just an explanation of a pattern that might fit this problem, and maybe a discussion of a common design for something like this. Am I right to avoid storing generate-able data like # of uses left? etc.)

Comment: Wait a second. Did you just say that you have that code in a *view*?

Comment: Rest assured that's actually a condensed version of my model and view. I use CodeIgniter, and things are separated quite nicely. Thanks for the concern though, and I would be concerned too if that were all in the "view".

Comment: Oh, good. Thanks, you saved my evening ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I right to avoid storing generate-able data like # of uses left?

Yes, you are correct to not store computed values.
Computation logic can change, and working with a stored computed value to reverse engineer it can be a nightmare - if it is possible at all in some cases.

It sounds like you want to combine the two queries:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.name, 
       c.uses, 
       c.code,
       x.num_used
  FROM CODES c
  JOIN (SELECT ed.code,
               COUNT(*) 'num_used'
          FROM ENTRY_DATA ed
      GROUP BY ed.code) x ON x.code = c.code
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your query to get the codes for the page add a subquery to get the number of used codes  from the entry_data table.

```
select codes.id, codes.name, codes.uses, codes.code (select count(code) from entry_data where entry_data.code=codes.code ) as used_codes
```

Id use code_id as a foreign key and not code.

This is all assuming i'm reading your problem correctly